# mozilla pdfjs text overlapped in specific situation

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, mozilla, pdfjs-dist

I'm facing a problem with mozilla pdfjs and after reading many github pages I'm here to seek some help.

There are two apps, one is a simple vue app(which I wrote for test), and another enterprise app using angular. In vue app, process of rendering PDF works just fine and scaling works, but in angular app texts are overlapping each other (before and after scale), while both are running on the exact same config (same OS and hardware) and result is same for every different PDF.

rendering result in vue
[image: 1]

rendering result in angular

[image: 2]

I know it is not a framework related issue, but I cannot figure out what causes this! fonts maybe? or some css properties?

pdfjs version : 2.14.305

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a little disappointing, since you might spent days on this, but I can surely say that with `direction:ltr` for page canvases class, your problem would be fixed.